# Windows 10 won't boot (Error code: 0xc000000f)

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

Last night my laptop got a blue screen and when I rebooted it, it quickly flashed a screen that said `Preparing automatic repair...` and then went into a blue screen that says my PC needs to be repaired. The error message I'm getting says that the OS can't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors (`werkernel.sys`) with the error code `0xc000000f`.

I'm not really sure what caused this as I haven't downloaded or installed anything at all recently. I was just watching a YouTube video when it crashed. Some additional information that might help:

- My laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro.
- I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu; Ubuntu still boots fine.
- A while back I moved my recovery partition onto a USB drive, which I still have.
- I'm able to get access to my BIOS menu and the command prompt.

Please let me know if you have any possible solutions or if there's any other information you need from me.

Answer (score 0):

This could have been caused by a virus which modified some important files in the windows folder. Try inserting the Windows CD and run the recovery which will repair the windows files. The fact you can still boot ubuntu makes me think is not a hardware issue.

Give a go to Archlinux one day, it's totally worth it.